# iOS/Swift: Add UITapGestureRecognizer to NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am wondering if it is possible to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to an `NSMutableAttributedString`.

What I am looking to do is have a "more..." object after the last word of a character-limited `UITextView`. In order for the object to appear immediatley after the last word, it seems best to make the `UITextView` accept attributed text (rather than plain text) and then append a blue "more..." of type `NSMutableAttributedString`.

I have seen examples of people accomplishing this by adding the tap gesture to the enclosing `UITextView`, but that is not sufficient as I wish for an action to occur only if they tap the "more..." at the end of the attributed string within the text view. I would like to see if there is a way to add a tap gesture directly to the attributed string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no way to add a gesture recogniser to a `NSMutableAttributedString` because an attributed string doesn't know anything about either its position in the screen or user touches.

The process to get an attributed string drawn in a `UITextView` is controlled mainly by three classes: `NSTextStorage`, `NSTextContainer` and `NSLayoutManager`. If you want to know a little bit more about how they work, check out [this awesome tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift).

After reading that tutorial you should know that you don't need to add a tap gesture recogniser to an attributed string to get what you want. If you don't need the `UITextView` to be editable, a solution would be to treat the blue `More...` as a link and attach a custom action to respond when the user touches it. Here is a Swift translation of the objective-c code in [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks) to illustrate how to achieve that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let str = NSMutableAttributedString(
          string: "This is a sample text that is very long but you can see it completely because More..."
      )
      str.addAttribute(
         NSLinkAttributeName,
         value: "more://",
         range: (str.string as NSString).range(of: "More...")
      )
  
      textView.attributedText = str
      textView.delegate = self
      textView.isSelectable = true
      textView.isEditable = false
   }

   func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
      if URL.scheme == "more" {
         print("TODO: Handle more action here")
         return false
      }
      else {
         return true
      }
   }
}
```